# jQuery AJAX post data gets lost

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to post data with AJAX and insert it into a database table.
The problem is, half of the data is missing and I don't know why. I have checked all the names of parameters etc. because it seemed I had a typo somewhere (I was missing some characters but I fixed that) but still it won't work.
Even console.log() and alerts give me the full data I want to post but it never arrives, the php outputs empty parameters. When deactivating the JavaScript or removing "return false;" the php script is opened as expected and works perfectly well, no data is lost (as expected).

Maybe I'm really just missing one single character somewhere ...
I also tried escaping (escape()) the strings but it didn't change anything.

Here's the code and some logs/alerts/echos

```
$("#itemspeichern").click(function(){
        setVisible("#item-process");

        var itemname = escape($("#itemname").val());
        if ($("#itemneu").is(":checked")) {  
            var itemneu = $("#itemneu").val();
        } else {
            var itemneu = 0;
        }
        var itembild = escape($("#itembild").val());
        var itemkurzb = escape($("#itemkurzb").val());
        var theset = escape($("#theset").val());

        console.log("itemname=" + itemname + "&itemneu=" + itemneu + "&itembild=" + itembild + "&itemkurzb=" + itemkurzb + "&theset=" + theset);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php actualPath(); ?>save-admin-action.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "itemname=" + itemname + "&itemneu=" + itemneu + "&itembild" + itembild + "&itemkurzb" + itemkurzb + "&theset=" + theset,
            success: function(result){
                alert("itemname=" + itemname + "&itemneu=" + itemneu + "&itembild=" + itembild + "&itemkurzb=" + itemkurzb + "&theset=" + theset);
                document.getElementById("item-process").innerHTML = result;
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

What this does is:
- output the data of all fields on the console
- showing all the data in the alert
but when it is done saving it the database is missing the values of itembild and itemkurzb. Getting the query as response from the php file showed that indeed the parameters are empty for those fields. Here's what I did in php (I shortened it a bit, don't comment on SQL injection and stuff :P)

```
$ergebnis = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mk7_items(id, de, neu, kurzbeschreibung, bild) VALUES(DEFAULT, '".$_POST["itemname"]."', ".$_POST["itemneu"].", '".$_POST["itemkurzb"]."', '".$_POST["itembild"]."')");
```

the last two fields are empty when I get the response and nothing is saved into the db.
As I said, setting JS to OFF and running it on php only works perfectly well.

Any ideas? Any stupid mistakes I did there?

Comment: Hm, some linebreaks are missing, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a couple `=` in your `data`, it should be this:

```
data: "itemname=" + itemname + "&itemneu=" + itemneu + "&itembild=" + itembild + "&itemkurzb=" + itemkurzb + "&theset=" + theset,
```

Or better, stop using [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape) (which is deprecated in favor or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) due to `escape` not handling non-ASCII data very well) and use an object for your `data` parameter:

```
var itemname = $("#itemname").val();
//...

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php actualPath(); ?>save-admin-action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        itemname:  itemname,
        itemneu:   itemneu,
        itembild:  itembild,
        itemkurzb: itemkurzb,
        theset:    theset
    },
    //...
});
```

That way [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will take care of converting your data to the proper POST (or GET or ...) format and you don't have to worry about the details.

Comment: Funny. I noticed the missing "=" as well and thought I changed it. But it seems I only did that for the logs ... thanks for the additional hints, I will keep that in mind

Comment: @User1021052: Sounds like a good argument for using the object literal version of `data` :)

Answer (score 2):

try this in your `$.ajax` call instead of your selfmade query string:

```
data: {
  itemname: itemname, 
  itemneu: itemneu, 
  itembild: itembild, 
  itemkurzb: itemkurzb, 
  theset: theset
}
```

By passing the data as Object, jQuery will escape the values for you :)

Edit:

You could also [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the complete form like this:

```
data: $('#yourform').serialize()
```

Comment: I will take a look into that. I saw that somewhere and tried using it but got syntax errors (expected { although I had it the way you posted). Thanks a lot for the hints

Answer (score 0):

if you use special characters in posted items, you use this function before every vars...
sample :

```
var txt = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txt1').value);
```